# Rails upgrade error A secret is required to generate an integrity hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

So I just upgraded from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3. Then from rails 2.3.18 to rails 3.0.20 but I'm running into this error

> A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb

I have searched and seen all of the questions about this that say you need to add

```
MyApp::Application.config.secret_token = 'secret'
```

and I have that in my config/initializers/secret_token.rb. What else could give me this error?

I also have:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => 'some_key'
```

in my config/initializers/session_store.rb

I believe I could have missed something during my upgrade which is causing this error?

**EDIT**:

I was missing this in my environment.rb

```
TheHockeyCommunity::Application.initialize!
```

Now its working fine!

Cheers

Comment: Do you literally have `MyApp::Application.config.secret_token = 'secret'` in your secret_token.rb? Because `'secret'` is not at least 30 characters.

Comment: lol no secret is 128 char key, some_key is different as well

Comment: ok cool, just wanted to check! :) Another stupid check: you've restarted your server since editing that file, right? The only other thing I found that it could be is this nasty bug: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4652

Comment: Yep restarted numerous times. I'll check out that bug thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you're missing some of the changes to the config files that you need in Rails 3 and your intitializer isn't being included. I made the same upgrade recently, you can [check my changes](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/userstyles/commit/3d41c8d59f40a60e2ce0d52cb4cf753b2a29c45c). There's a lot of changes there that won't be useful to you, but pay attention to any changes to files at the root of the application and under `config`.

Also, make sure you have your app name (matching the `initialize!` line in config/environment.rb) and not "MyApp".

Comment: Yep app name matches, I will go through your commit and see what I missed.